# Get ContentType id in Django for generic relation

Tags: django

I'm porting a project from Rails to Django with a legacy database.  In Rails I had a polymorphic association that allowed me to add a footnote to any row in the database.  I'm trying to implement the same thing in the Django app.  I found the documentation on Generic Relations and it looks perfect.  Unfortunately, I first need to create new fields in my legacy database to hold the ContentType id for the relevant models.  I only used the polymorphic association with 2 tables, so all I need are those two corresponding ids from the Django app, but I can't seem to find the appropriate command for looking up a ContentType id in Django.

Any suggestions are most welcome.  I tried searching through previous questions but couldn't seem to find what I am looking for.  Thank you very much for you time and help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.generic.GenericForeignKey)

you can do:

```
>>> b = Bookmark.objects.get(url='https://www.djangoproject.com/')
>>> bookmark_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(b)
>>> TaggedItem.objects.filter(content_type__pk=bookmark_type.id,
...                           object_id=b.id)
```

so just instantiate an instance of your model and then do `ContentType.objects.get_for_model(<instance>).id`

I think there's a way to pass just the model name, too... let me know if that would work better and I'll try to find it; I've used it in the past.

Comment: Thanks!  It looks like I might have been getting the answer I needed before, I just didn't realize it.  Are ContentType ids typically strings?  Each number is followed by an 'L' -- content_type_id for Letter is "43L" for Assignment is "44L".

Comment: So I still don't know what is up with the 'L', but I just did what I should have done in the first place and went into the underlying database to look at the table.  Sure enough, the numbers I was getting are correct but the L is nowhere to be found.  Weird.  But many, many thanks!

Comment: The L is a very annoying Django thing-- the id type is "long int" in the db, so in some circumstances it comes out with the L appended. If you cast it to an int (`int(44L)`), you should get 44.

Comment: Ah.  All is now clear.  Thanks for taking the time to explain!

Comment: "L" is appended for all primary keys and foreign keys by default with MySQL due to the use of long int, so that's a guess. Django is usually good at coercion in queryset evaluation though, so you don't often have to worry about it.

Comment: For Django 3, `ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Bookmark)` (not instance) works fine as of today.

Answer (score 10):

You can also get `ContentType` ID without creating an instance, which is more efficient if you don't have and don't need an instance but just want to get `ContentType` ID by model name.

`ContentType.objects.get(model='bookmark').id`

**Notes** : if the name of your model is upper case, please use lower case to search. For example: `model = 'bookmark'` rather than `'Bookmark'`